# How do I regexp-match (remove) an arbitrary series of two-letter language codes separated by commas, to the right of a title?

Tags: regex, pcre

I have a bunch of strings such as:

```
Super Mario Bros. 8 (En,Fr,De,Es,It)
Donald Duck in Whacky Land (En,Fr,De,Es,Sv)
Toadstool Adventures 3D (En)
Chinaland (En,De)
A title which doesn't have any such thing
...
```

That is, a title of a product followed by (sometimes) a list of one or more language codes in parentheses.

I really struggle to come up with a (PCRE) regexp to safely remove these from the strings in a safe manner. That is, not likely to touch the titles.

I know that `([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1})` must be involved somewhere, to match a single language code such as "It" or "De", but how I should handle the possibility of any number of such in a row, with commas between or no comma (if it's just one), is beyond my regular expression skills.

I really wish that they had used some kind of unambiguous separator between the title part and the "metadata" part of the filenames... Then I wouldn't need to do all this manual trial-and-error removal. But they didn't.

Comment: why not just remove `(anything inside the  parentheses)`?

Comment: @missuse Because titles can have parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```perl
\([A-Z][a-z](?:,[A-Z][a-z])*\)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/xxNQ8h/1

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
\(([A-Z][a-z],?)+\).*$
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8RP5Ku/2)

Comment: Albeit unlikely, this would capture wrong stuff like `(GoTo)`